# Create a new column for an unstack dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have an unstack dataframe like this:

```
churn_label No  Yes
under_30        
No      4077    1564
Yes     1097    304
```

and I need to add a new column that give the total in an already unstack dataframe

```
churn_label No  Yes   Total
under_30        
No         4077 1564   5174
Yes        1097 304    1868
```

I tried this:

```
data_df = customer_churn_df.groupby(["under_30", "churn_label"]).count()

data_df["total_count"] = data_df["customer_id"].unstack(level = -1).sum()

data_df["total_count"]
```

And this is what I get:

```
under_30  churn_label
No        No            NaN
          Yes           NaN
Yes       No            NaN
          Yes           NaN
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: churn_label No  Yes   Total
    under_30        
    No         4077 1564   5174
    Yes        1097 304    1868

Answer (score 0):

```
# Group by using the variables under_30 and churn_label then count occurances
data_df = customer_churn_df.groupby(["under_30", "churn_label"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

# Add the  total_count column
data_df["total_count"] = data_df.sum(axis=1)
# Change total_count to Total if needed, from your question I couldnt decide which do you prefered
```